# Do you need a wheel alignment after changing a tyre?

Tags: alignment

Will be changing a tyre due to low tread. I’ve heard you should get an alignment done afterwards but then I’ve heard thered no need.

What is the truth?

Comment: Having tires on the same axle with a large difference in tread can also cause issues.

Comment: If you're going to get the alignment for the one tire, you might want to replace the other on the same axle if it's worn  and save on another alignment in the future when you would have replaced it.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing saying "you have to get an alignment", but it's a good thing to do if you want to protect your investment of a new tire. The thing is, though, the alignment may not be the underlying problem, so just getting an alignment done might not fix the reason the tire was unevenly worn in the first place. You need to look at it holistically and see if there are any other issues which needs to be addressed. If there isn't, getting an alignment is still a good idea ... but there's no mandate on it.